# How to run Granger Causality tests with GPU in Python?

Tags: python, statistics, gpu, statsmodels

I wonder if there is any statistics library for running Granger Causality tests using GPU, as I have to run many tests and now it's taking a lot of time.

I know about the statsmodels package function for the Granger Causality ([statsmodels.tsa.stattools.grangercausalitytests](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.grangercausalitytests.html)), but if I try to take advantage of this function using GPU I find that it looks like it doesn't work with @jit(nopython=True). Without the nopython=True it works, but then it doesn't speed the performance.

Something similar to the R package [gputools](https://rdrr.io/cran/gputools/src/R/gpuGranger.R) that seems to work properly with GPU, but for Python.

Comment: You would need to code it from scratch using `numba`.

Comment: I see, thank you for confirming it. I guess I will migrate that part of code to R, as it will be faster for this time. But as soon as I have some free time, I will try to implement it on Python.